# I'm having issues with installing tts-generation-webui

Tags: github, machine-learning, pip, voice, miniconda

I'm new to using machine learning programs on Github, and decided to try my hand at machine learning by installing tts-generation-webui.
I followed the instructions as intended, installing the program via the one-click installer, but have struggled to get it to work. Although the UI showed, the UI would throw errors when accepting custom data (such as the native Bark Voice Clone or Tortoise-TTS.)
The errors on the console:
On startup via start_windows.bat:

```
- 2023-07-23 18:13:18 | WARNING | xformers | WARNING[XFORMERS]: xFormers can't load C++/CUDA extensions. xFormers was built for:
    PyTorch 2.0.1+cu118 with CUDA 1108 (you have 2.0.1+cpu)
    Python  3.10.11 (you have 3.10.12)
  Please reinstall xformers (see https://github.com/facebookresearch/xformers#installing-xformers)
  Memory-efficient attention, SwiGLU, sparse and more won't be available.
  Set XFORMERS_MORE_DETAILS=1 for more details
- 2023-07-23 18:13:18 | WARNING | xformers | Triton is not available, some optimizations will not be enabled. This is just a warning: No module named 'triton'
And when I tried running anything other than Generation (Bark) (long one, user censored for privacy)
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[CENSORED]\Downloads\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\installer_files\env\lib\site-packages\gradio\routes.py", line 437, in run_predict
    output = await app.get_blocks().process_api(
  File "C:\Users\[CENSORED]\Downloads\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\installer_files\env\lib\site-packages\gradio\blocks.py", line 1352, in process_api
    result = await self.call_function(
  File "C:\Users\[CENSORED]\Downloads\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\installer_files\env\lib\site-packages\gradio\blocks.py", line 1077, in call_function
    prediction = await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(
  File "C:\Users\[CENSORED]\Downloads\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\installer_files\env\lib\site-packages\anyio\to_thread.py", line 33, in run_sync
    return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
  File "C:\Users\[CENSORED]\Downloads\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\installer_files\env\lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 877, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
  File "C:\Users\[CENSORED]\Downloads\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\installer_files\env\lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 807, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
  File "C:\Users\[CENSORED]\Downloads\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\tts-generation-webui\src\bark\clone\tab_voice_clone.py", line 222, in generate_voice
    full_generation = get_prompts(wav_file, use_gpu)
  File "C:\Users\[CENSORED]\Downloads\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\tts-generation-webui\src\bark\clone\tab_voice_clone.py", line 87, in get_prompts
    semantic_prompt = get_semantic_prompt(path_to_wav, device)
  File "C:\Users\[CENSORED]\Downloads\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\tts-generation-webui\src\bark\clone\tab_voice_clone.py", line 81, in get_semantic_prompt
    semantic_vectors = get_semantic_vectors(path_to_wav, device)
  File "C:\Users\[CENSORED]\Downloads\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\tts-generation-webui\src\bark\clone\tab_voice_clone.py", line 46, in get_semantic_vectors
    hubert_model = _load_hubert_model(device)
  File "C:\Users\[CENSORED]\Downloads\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\tts-generation-webui\src\bark\clone\tab_voice_clone.py", line 26, in _load_hubert_model
    hubert_model = CustomHubert(
  File "C:\Users\[CENSORED]\Downloads\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\installer_files\env\lib\site-packages\bark_hubert_quantizer\pre_kmeans_hubert.py", line 65, in __init__
    model[0].to(device)
  File "C:\Users\[CENSORED]\Downloads\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\installer_files\env\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1145, in to
    return self._apply(convert)
  File "C:\Users\[CENSORED]\Downloads\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\installer_files\env\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 797, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "C:\Users\[CENSORED]\Downloads\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\installer_files\env\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 797, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "C:\Users\[CENSORED]\Downloads\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\installer_files\env\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 797, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
  File "C:\Users\[CENSORED]\Downloads\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\installer_files\env\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 820, in _apply
    param_applied = fn(param)
  File "C:\Users\[CENSORED]\Downloads\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\installer_files\env\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1143, in convert
    return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None, non_blocking)
  File "C:\Users\[CENSORED]\Downloads\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\one-click-installers-tts-6.0\installer_files\env\lib\site-packages\torch\cuda\__init__.py", line 239, in _lazy_init
    raise AssertionError("Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled")
AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled**
```

Some of the things that I've tried so far (probably not good ideas in hindsight)

- Updating to PyTorch 2.0
- Trying to manually install xformers (without knowing where it goes)
- Reinstalling PyTorch

I've tried to fix this on my own according to some questionable advise, but none of my attempts have worked. Can someone help point out what I need to do to get the software running properly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.